# How to validate multiple controls of different types on the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, requiredfieldvalidator, customvalidator

I'm working with Telerik tools version 2013.1.417.45.
This is all part of a C# web project using .NET 4.5.

I have the following controls and multiples of each except the list box.

> radAsyncUpload
>   RadListBox
>   RadTextBox

Is there a way I can validate that they are all populated prior to sending anything to the server? I have tried the required field validator but that works for the text box controls but not the other two. I'm not sure with a custom validator if I can check multiple controls.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at some jQuery to help validate the controls. Take a looksie at this

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-Form-Validation-Example-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Thank you.  I'm on a super tight deadline would it be better to make this checks on the server side and not do anything if something isn't entered or selected?

Comment: what are you trying to validate ? is it just required fields ?

Comment: Yes, required fields.  The text box ones are fine it's the list box and I have 2 radAsyncUpload (Telerik) controls that I have to check as well.  I'm doing it on the server side now, but I would like to do it on the client.

Comment: I have removed the radAsyncUpload controls and I'm using the asp:fileupload control.  This is causing an issue because my Captcha posts to the server which causes these controls to be cleared.

Comment: first , if you want to validate on the client side, do not use asp server side controls.

Comment: I just want to validate that they are populated or selected on the client but I need to do stuff with the data that is populated.  What would be a better approach if I don't use server side controls and then how do I get my data into the database tables?     Thx